# Error when validating the head tag

Tags: html

I am getting this error when validating my html code 
element head is missing a required instance of child element title

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <div id="head">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </div>

    <body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="allposts.php">All Posts</a></li>

            </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You may want include what *this error* is to describe your problem . it's not always clear from the code provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. try removing

```
<div id="head">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </div>
```

And replace it with

```
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  </head>
```

This will surely work well. Trust me.

Your head also needs a `title` tag.

```
   <title> My website </title>
```

The whole thing should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>My website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
 Your page content
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

it mut look like this:
`<head>` is a tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="allposts.php">All Posts</a></li>

        </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

An `html` tag requires a `head` tag, which in turn requires a `title` tag.  You're missing these things.  Instead, you're trying to use a `div` as a `head`, which is very invalid.  I think you meant this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Some Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
...
```